# Taking 45 minutes time to make --prod --aot build of angular2 project when number of components are large, How to resolve this?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot, aot, angular-aot

we have implemented ANGULAR application by using Angular ~2.4.0 and webpack ^1.10.2.

it was implemented by Phase 1 and Phase 2 development.

after completion of Phase 1 development it tooks only 10 minutes of time to generate aot build.

but the problem starts after merging of Phase 2 development code with initial phase, now the aot build takes 45 minutes to generate build.

my question is there any techniques to reduce aot build generate time?

Thanks in advance.

[image: screen appears like this for 45 minutes]

command line blinking for 45 minutes without any indication.

Comment: When you get stuck on command line, what does it say ?

Comment: @David its simply shows like blinking.

Comment: So there is no indication of the current step, like tree shaking, sass, uglyfyjs,.. ?

Comment: yes, there is no indication as you mentioned.